# how to configure deployment slots in Microsoft azure using SSL

Tags: azure, ssl, deployment

We are hosting a web app on MS Azure which is using SSL. We are planning to use deployment slots to do the testing on a slot before we roll the changes to live, followed by a swap.

According to this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/) in azure documentation `*some configuration elements will follow the content across a swap (not slot specific) while other configuration elements will stay in the same slot after a swap (slot specific).*`

'SSL certificates and bindings' is a setting which won't be swapped. Does that mean we can't use the slots for SSL websites (as the SSL is IP based) or we will have to manually add  that setting and upload the SSL certficate in the pre production testing slot before swapping?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box Azure provides an SSL certificate for their websites... though as you can see Chrome doesn't like it. :-)

This also applies for each slot that you create.  If you are ok with the testing URL being yourdomain-slotname.azurewebsites.net I'd assume this will work for you.  Else I guess you'd have to buy a wild card certificate that matches your domain and setup the configuration to match.

[image]

Comment: You can use alt names instead of a wild card for a fixed number of urls.